# Mybatis batch update using foreach tag reports an error:ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptio

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, mybatis

Entity:

```
@TableName(value = "gas_mode_dtl")
@ApiModel(value = "gasModeDtl", description = "气调模式明细")
@Data
public class GasModeDtl extends AbstractEntity{
    /**
    * 主键标识
    */
    @TableId(value = "fid")
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "主键标识", name = "fid", dataType = "String")
    private String fid;

    /**
    * 设备配置id
    */
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "设备配置id", name = "deviceConfId", dataType = "String")
    private String deviceConfId;

    /**
    * 模式标识
    */
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "模式标识", name = "modeId", dataType = "String")
    private String modeId;

    /**
    * 控制状态
    */
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "控制状态", name = "controlStatus", dataType = "Integer")
    private Integer controlStatus;

    /**
    * 备用字段1
    */
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "备用字段1", name = "field1", dataType = "String")
    private String field1;

    /**
    * 备用字段2
    */
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "备用字段2", name = "field2", dataType = "String")
    private String field2;

    /**
    * 备用字段3
    */
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "备用字段3", name = "field3", dataType = "String")
    private String field3;

    /**
    * 备用字段4
    */
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "备用字段4", name = "field4", dataType = "String")
    private String field4;

    /**
    * 备用字段5
    */
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "备用字段5", name = "field5", dataType = "String")
    private String field5;

}
```

Mapper:

```
 /**
     * 批量更新
     *
     * @param list 数据集合
     */
    void batchUpdate(@Param("list") List<GasModeDtl> list);
```

SQL：

```
<update id="batchUpdate" parameterType="java.util.List">
        <if test="list != null and list.size() > 0">
            <foreach collection="list" item="item" index="index" separator=";">
                UPDATE gas_mode_dtl
                <set>
                    <if test="item.deviceConfId != null and item.deviceConfId != ''">
                        device_conf_id = #{item.deviceConfId},
                    </if>
                    <if test="item.modeId != null and item.modeId != ''">
                        mode_id = #{item.modeId},
                    </if>
                    <if test="item.controlStatus != null">
                        control_status = #{item.controlStatus},
                    </if>
                    <if test="item.field1 != null and item.field1 != ''">
                        field1 = #{item.field1},
                    </if>
                    <if test="item.field2 != null and item.field2 != ''">
                        field2 = #{item.field2},
                    </if>
                    <if test="item.field3 != null and item.field3 != ''">
                        field3 = #{item.field3},
                    </if>
                    <if test="item.field4 != null and item.field4 != ''">
                        field4 = #{item.field4},
                    </if>
                    <if test="item.field5 != null and item.field5 != ''">
                        field5 = #{item.field5}
                    </if>
                </set>
                WHERE fid = #{item.fid,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
            </foreach>
        </if>
    </update>
```

Error message:

```
nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not set parameters for mapping: ParameterMapping{property='__frch_item_1.deviceConfId', mode=IN, javaType=class java.lang.String, jdbcType=null, numericScale=null, resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #4 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
```

I have confirmed that there are no extra comments or single quotes, and that the incoming parameter type corresponds to the entity type, and the data type corresponds to the data type in the table.
I have tested that if the incoming collection has only one element, it can be updated successfully. But passing in two or more will report this exception. And the number of out-of-bounds changes with the number of sets. set has only one parameter, and when the if tag is removed, the exception is also reported.
I hope you can help me determine the cause of the anomaly and give me a solution.

Comment: If you are using 3rd party extensions like mybatis-page-helper, mybatis-plus, etc., see if the problem reproduces without them. Some extensions try to modify the SQL via plugin and it is known to cause problems like `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Also note that concatenating multiple statements with `;` is not the recommended way when updating many rows. The recommended way is to use the batch executor. See the [FAQ entry](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-code-a-batch-insert).

Comment: You are executing multiple updates in a single call. That could prove to be difficult to debug. I would make separate UPDATE calls, to find out which set of parameters is causing the issue.